# How to include a JavaScript object in a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object

I'm trying to include a separate .js file so I can pull in a class I created but it doesn't work, can someone tell me why?

playercharacter.js

```
function PlayerCharacter() {
this.x = 0; 
this.y = 0;

this.dx = 5;
this.dy = 5;
}


PlayerCharacter.prototype.sayHello = function()
{
 alert ('hello');
};
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/playercharacter.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
var player = new PlayerCharacter();
player.sayHello();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put an `alert()` outside any function in "playercharacter.js" to make sure that it's being loaded at all.

Comment: Why does this code sample start with "PSEUDO"? It doesn't appear to be pseudocode.

Comment: I put an alert in, and you're right - it's not executing?

I checked the file paths - indexh.html is in root and js file is in a fodler called js ...

Comment: What in the world, I uploaded this example as a zip file...doesn't get any simpler than this, so why doesn't it work?
http://www.ryandebraal.com/HTML5_test3.zip

Comment: Yes, it's definitely advisable to set the path to the correct fodler.

Comment: in my atached sample, can you see why it's not working? cause its as basic as I can reduce it yet still doesn't work?!

Comment: Crap. the reason it wasn't working is because the playercharacter.js, had no extension....it was just called playercharacter...didn't add extension when I created it :/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot wrap your JS-code into the `<script>` tags

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/playercharacter.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   var player = new PlayerCharacter();
   player.sayHello();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is not in a `script` tag.

```
<script>
    var player = new PlayerCharacter();
    player.sayHello();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the code in the body with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Mobile SO doesn't notify of new answers.

Comment: Ok ;) Didin't know that hehe.